# Zoom instance for Coroutine (Await Int) (State MyState) Int

Tags: haskell, zooming, coroutine, haskell-lens

I have a deeply nested state `MyState` which is used inside a `Coroutine` (from [monad-coroutine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine) package):

```
Coroutine (Await Int) (State MyState) Int
```

And I like the possibility of using zoom (from [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)) to do some manipulation, because it allows me to write something like

```
zoom (company.assets) $ do
   a.b = 3
   c.d = 'good'
   ...
```

Unfortunately for me I cannot come up with correct declaration of `instance Zoom` for the `Coroutine` I have.

My attempt to do so was something like this:

```
instance Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) s t where
    zoom l (Coroutine m) = undefined
```

But already at this point GHC tells me

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘s’
The third argument of ‘Zoom’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘s’ has kind ‘* -> *’
In the instance declaration for
  ‘Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) s t’
```

But if I do something like

```
instance Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) (s a) (t a) where
    zoom l (Coroutine m) = undefined
```

Then GHC is complaining:

```
Illegal instance declaration for
  ‘Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) (s a) (t a)’
  The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘Zoom’
    for functional dependency: ‘m -> s’
  Reason: lhs type ‘Coroutine z s’ does not determine rhs type ‘s a’
In the instance declaration for
  ‘Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) (s a) (t a)’
```

Now I understand I'm attempting to do something blindly without understanding what is actually expected from me. Anyone could explain the way `Zoom` instance is defined for something like my `Coroutine` and why it is defined (so not only interested in the correct declaration but also some notes of the thinking process when constructing such declaration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By error

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘s’
The third argument of ‘Zoom’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘s’ has kind ‘* -> *’
In the instance declaration for
  ‘Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) s t’
```

GHC is complaining the kind mismatch here

```
  ‘Zoom (Coroutine z s) (Coroutine z t) s t’
                     ^                  ^
```

The second type parameter of `Coroutine` should be a monad (`* -> *`), while `s` is the type of the state (`*`) as the third type parameter of `Zoom`. The instance declaration should be

```
instance (Functor f, Zoom m n s t) => Zoom (Coroutine f m) (Coroutine f n) s t
```

Along with some boilerplate to satisfy the context of `Zoom`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances  #-}

instance (Functor f, MonadState s m) => MonadState s (Coroutine f m) where
  get = lift get
  put = lift . put

type instance Zoomed (Coroutine s m) = Zoomed m
```

---

After a few hours of inspection I realized what I suggested above is impossible to implement, the type of `zoom` is too restricted to be used with `mapMonad` and I don't know a way to overcome it. However it still will work if everything is monomorphic:

```
data MyState = MyState
  { _myRecord :: String }

$(makeLenses ''MyState)

zoomMyState :: Functor f => Coroutine f (State String) r -> Coroutine f (State MyState) r
zoomMyState = mapMonad (zoom myRecord)
```

Comment: Even though I can follow your explanation the definition is still bringing me trouble. So simply `zoom l (Coroutine m) = Coroutine (zoom l m)` doesn't work. I guess it's because we need to reach `State` in Coroutine stack. But I'm having troubles figuring it out

Comment: @ksaveljev try `mapMonad` from monad coroutine package.

Comment: `zoom l m = mapMonad (zoom l) m` still gives me an error where it says that `Could not deduce (y ~ c)` and `Expected type: Control.Lens.Type.LensLike' (Zoomed m y) t s
      Actual type: Control.Lens.Type.LensLike' (Zoomed (Coroutine f m) c) t s`

Comment: @ksaveljev my fault, I just realized it's somehow impossible to define a polymorphic `zoom` on `Coroutine` (as my restricted knowledge of `lens` suggests, sorry), but it will still work if you supply all the type parameters.